# Is there a way for JSON to enable object mapping to reduce string size?

Tags: arrays, json, encode

Lets say for example we have an array of objects were going to encode.

```
// duplicate child objects, unnecessary json output.
$biggerJsonData = [
    'messages' => [
        [
            'content' => 'hi',
            'user' => [
                'id' => 1,
                'name' => 'John'
            ]
        ],
        [
            'content' => 'hi from same user',
            'user' => [
                'id' => 1,
                'name' => 'John'
             ]
        ],
    ]
];

// mapped child objects
$smallerJsonData = [
    'messages' => [
        [
            'content' => 'hi',
            'user' => 'map(users-1)'
        ],
        [
            'content' => 'hi from same user',
            'user' => 'map(users-1)'
        ],
    ],
    '_map' => [
        'users-1' => [
           'id' => 1,
           'name' => 'John'
        ]

    ]
];

json_decode(json_encode($smallerJsonData), true)['messages'][0]['user']['name'] // john
json_decode(json_encode($biggerJsonData), true)['messages'][0]['user']['name'] // john
```

The $smallerJsonData would be parsed exactly like the data structure of $biggerData, but the encoding part would include a mapping to reduce string encoding size. Is there anything like this in JSON where it will automatically do child object mapping if they are exactly the same object? This could save a lot of string size for bigger data loads.